# Phone is booting with a specific battery on Samsung Galaxy S3 with CyanogenMod11

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery, hardware

Yesterday my Samsung Galaxy S3 fell and shut down.

I have tried many solutions to turn it on but the only thing I could do was to enter **download mode**.

Today I tried to replace its battery with my old one's battery and the phone is working good!

So what with the other battery could be problematic?

Both batteries must be good because I can turn on the cell with them (even though with one of them I can't boot past download mode) and the rest of the hardware must also be fine because phone works fine.